# Facebook SDK loads default image and not image from my profile, why?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got these facebook permissions set in my app:

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"user_games_activity", 
                                    @"friends_games_activity",
                                    @"publish_actions",
                                    @"user_photos",
                                    nil];
            [[myDelegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
```

I'm making a request like so :

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name,picture",@"fields",nil];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

And handling the response like :

```
else if([request.url rangeOfString:@"me"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *username = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"We think the username is %@", username);
        helloGreeting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", username];


        NSString *pictureUrl = [result objectForKey:@"picture"];
        NSLog(@"Now loading image [%@]", pictureUrl);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl]];
        profilePhoto.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];  
    }
```

The log output I get is :

```
2012-06-26 15:10:49.002 FacebookIntegrator[10549:f803] We think the username is James Elsey
2012-06-26 15:10:49.003 FacebookIntegrator[10549:f803] Now loading image [http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif]
```

[image]

**Question** : Why does it obtain a default generic facebook icon rather than my own profile picture? Using the same access tokens on the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=563645402/picture) I can get to my profile picture image URL

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) for `user_photos` states :

> Provides access to the photos the user has uploaded, and photos the
>   user has been tagged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User profile picture do not require `user_photos` permissions.  Picture is likely coming from facebook cache, you should use following url for picture.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<facebook id>/picture
```